# Recoding a semicolon separated list in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R and am struggling to to figure this out. I have a data fame with a column of character vectors that contain comma separated lists of things. I want to keep that column but add a column for each item with a value of 0 (not in the list) or 1 (in the list).

Here's what's I'm trying:

```
library("tidyverse")

colors <- c("red;blue", "red;green")
df <- data.frame(colors, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df %>%
  mutate(green = case_when("green" %in% strsplit(colors,";")[[1]] ~ 1, 
                         TRUE ~ 0))
```

The result I get is:

```
     colors green
1  red;blue     0
2 red;green     0
```

I expected the value for "green" in the second row to be 1.

To try to debug this I tried this:

```
> strsplit("red;green", ";")
[[1]]
[1] "red"   "green"

> "green" %in% strsplit("red;green",";")[[1]]
[1] TRUE

# and the negative case
> "green" %in% strsplit("red;blue",";")[[1]]
[1] FALSE
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `str_detect`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
      mutate(green = +(str_detect(colors, 'green')))
```

#### Update

If we wanted new columns

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(df, mtabulate(strsplit(df$colors, ";")))
#     colors blue green red
#1  red;blue    1     0   1
#2 red;green    0     1   1
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
cbind(df, as.data.frame.matrix(table(stack(setNames(strsplit(df$colors, ";"), 
                 seq_along(df$colors)))[2:1])))
```

---

In the OP's, code, the `strsplit` `list` first element (`[[1]]`) is selected instead of looping over the list, resulting in recycling of the element and getting FALSE as there is no 'green' in the first `list` element

```
library(purrr)
df %>%
   mutate(green = map_int(strsplit(colors, ";"), 
               ~ case_when('green' %in% .x ~ 1L, TRUE ~ 0L)))
#     colors green
#1  red;blue     0
#2 red;green     1
```

Comment: Perfect! In my real data I have values like "green;blue green;greenish yellow" so I don't think str_detect works (which is why I was trying to use strsplit), right?

Comment: except that ```str_detect("blue green", "\\bgreen\\b")``` gives a false positive (because it's not _just_ "green").

Comment: I super appreciate it as I'm just learning. You answered my question most directly, but @Sathith's solution solves the bigger problem of coding lots of columns (without needing to code separately for each value).

Comment: @MattGalloway for your updated geeneral casee, i updated

Answer (score 5):

With a `data.table` solution, you can use `tstrsplit`:

```r
library(data.table)

df <- data.table::data.table(
  color = c("red;blue", "red;green")
)

df[, c("col1","col2") := tstrsplit(color, ";", fixed = TRUE)] 
df[, "green" := (col2 == "green")]

df

#       color col1  col2 green
# 1:  red;blue  red  blue FALSE
# 2: red;green  red green  TRUE
```

If you are not familiar with `data.table` update-by-reference operator `:=`, `data.table` vignettes are a good place to start. The option `fixed = TRUE` in `tstrsplit` assumes that you always have the same number of elements in your comma separated list.

There is a solution that, I think, is more adapted to a situation where you have more than a few values. Using repetitively `lapply`, you can add a series of columns to your `data.table`

Starting back with `df`:

```r
df <- data.table::data.table(
  color = c("red;blue", "red;green")
)
```

Calling `lapply` with `grepl` to scan for the relevent color, we update by reference our object (note that you could use more than three colors):

```r
lapply(c("red","green","blue"), function(x){
  df[grepl(x, color), c(as.character(x)) := TRUE]
})
#[[1]]

#[[2]]
#       color  red green blue
#1:  red;blue TRUE    NA TRUE
#2: red;green TRUE  TRUE   NA

#[[3]]
#       color  red green blue
#1:  red;blue TRUE    NA TRUE
#2: red;green TRUE  TRUE   NA
```

There is no need to re-assign the dataframe. It has been updated by reference. Only the last slot of `df` interests us. Finally, by selecting this one and setting `NAs` to `FALSE`:

```r
df <- df[[length(df)]]
df[is.na(df)] <- FALSE

df
#       color  red green  blue
# 1:  red;blue TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# 2: red;green TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 4):

**Data**

```
colors <- c("red;blue", "red;green")
df <- data.frame(colors, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**Code**

```
cbind.data.frame(colors,
                 sapply( unique(unlist(strsplit( unlist(df), ";", fixed = TRUE))), 
                         function(x) as.integer(grepl(x, colors))))
```

**Output**

```
#      colors red blue green
# 1  red;blue   1    1     0
# 2 red;green   1    0     1
```

**Using `%in%` and no regular expression on a different dataset with similar items: green and greenish**

```
colors <- c("red;blue;greenish", "red;green")
df <- data.frame(colors, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

myfun <- function(x) { unique(unlist(strsplit( unlist(x), ";", fixed = TRUE))) }
df2 <- t(sapply( df$colors, function(x) { as.integer(myfun(df) %in% myfun(x))}))
colnames(df2) <- myfun(df)
df2
#                   red blue greenish green
# red;blue;greenish   1    1        1     0
# red;green           1    0        0     1
```

Answer (score 3):

`%in%` does not work that way. Try `grepl`

```
df %>% mutate(green = case_when(grepl("green",colors) ~ 1,TRUE ~ 0)
```